# Is there way faster way to edit xlsm file other than openpyxl?

Tags: python, xlsm

```
file='excel.xlsm'
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
sheet=wb['Template']
rowx=['x','y','z']
rows=sheet.max_row
sheet.cell(row=rows+1, column=j+1).value=row[j]
wb.save(file)
```

I have an xlsm file and I have tried edit it using openpyxl. But there is a problem. When I try to edit a xlsm which has 4 or 5 templates, the size of the file is 4-5 mb which takes a lot of time to load when using openpyxl. Is there any way that I can modify my current file faster without having to create a new one?

Comment: Try to use a different file format. xlsm is a very complex format that contains data, formulas, macros and presentation. I assume that the Python part will only process the data. If it makes sense, try to export the data part into a simpler format (csv), process that with your Python code, and then load it back into Excel. Of course, the export/import operations will have some overhead...

Answer (score 0):

An `.xlsx` or `.xlsm` file is basically a bunch of XML files wrapped up in a zip file.

In my scripts repo I have an example ([`unlock-excel.py`](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/master/unlock-excel.py)) where I use the `zipfile` module to open and modify an excel file. (In this case removing the `<sheetProtect>` and `<workbookProtect>` elements from the pages)

What I learned about the excel file format for creating this program is documented in [this article](/home/rsmith/WWW/src/howto/reading-xlsx-files-with-python.rst) on my website. The highlights:

An `xlsx` (or `xlsm`) file is basically a zip-file with a standard directory structure and a gaggle of XML files. When unpacking these files, I generally found the following directories.

```
> mkdir foo
> cd foo
> unzip ../foo.xlsx
> find . -type d|sort
.
./_rels
./docProps
./xl
./xl/_rels
./xl/printerSettings
./xl/theme
./xl/worksheets
./xl/worksheets/_rels
```

The `_rels` directories don't matter for this purpose.

The `docProps` directory contains two files; `app.xml` and `core.xml`. The `app.xml` file basically contained a list of the titles as seen on the tabs on the bottom of the worksheets. The titles are listed in this file in the sequence they appear in the xlsx file from left to right. They are bracketed between `<vt:lpstr>` and `</vt:lpstr>` tags.

The `workbook.xml` file in the `xl` directory contains a number of sheet definitions. These link the name of the worksheet to several numbers. Each sheet has a single tag with attributes, like this.

```
<sheet name="template" sheetId="4" r:id="rId1"/>
```

In the subdirectory `xl/worksheets` there is a number of XML files named `sheetN.xml`, where `N` is a number. *These are the actual worksheets.* One might expect that N corresponds with the sheetId. But that turns out not to be the case. The sheet number N actually is the number in the r:id attribute after the rId text. So in the example above, the worksheet named template is `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`.